# What is the typical spring rate for a racing car shock absorber and what does it depend on?

Tags: suspension, car, shock-absorber

I understand it depends on a lot of different factors and probably have a large range of #s. But could anyone give me some information about the range of the spring rate and where I can find more information about it? Just want to get an idea of what would be reasonable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of racing are you planning on doing? You aren't going to use the same springs for a track car as you would a drag car.

Comment: I'm actually not quiet sure. It's for a solar car racing. Sorry I'm totally new to this...

Comment: You will probably need to get them made , as solar cars are designed to minimum weight possible so any car application will probably be too strong. Some bike ones may be in the right ball-park. Remember that the spring and damper function as a complete unit so the rates are complementary - compression and extension are not identical...

Comment: What is the maintenance or repair question here?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry should have been posted as an answer. You will probably need to get them made , as solar cars are designed to minimum weight possible so any car application will probably be too strong. Some bike ones may be in the right ball-park. Remember that the spring and damper function as a complete unit so the rates are complementary - compression and extension are not identical... Or, for some bounce and rebound...

So, here are two sites that calculate springs:
http://www.hypercoils.com/spring-calculator
and
https://www.thespringstore.com/spring-calculator/spring-rate-calculator.html
And this site :
http://www.engineersedge.com/spring_comp_calc_k.htm
shows the calculation process.

Comment: Yes I figured we probably need to get specifically made ones. I'm trying to figure out is what the spring rate would be... Do you have any idea where I can find information about how to calculate that and what are the factors affecting it? Thanks for helping:)

Comment: See my edit : values necessary, note one site does suggest measure, change, test, change test etc to get the final best solution as you will probably not get the perfect spring first time.

Comment: What do you mean the rates of the spring and shock are complementary? And I finally figured out how to calculate the spring rate thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on a few factors but the main ones are; vehicle weight and vehicle weight distribution.

The relative unsprung weight will make a difference, as will transverse balance of the car.

Your best bet is to see a company to get the car "corner weighted" fully built up with the driver in.  Somewhere like Leda can do this type of work in conjunction with track time to fine tune spring and damping rates.

If you want to take the DIY approach, [this](http://www.turbosport.co.uk/showthread.php?t=153066) makes for interesting and fun reading.